# How to repair, merge, or "update" (using rsync ?) partially downloaded/backed up duplicate icloud archives?

Tags: terminal, icloud, backup, high-sierra, rsync

When I used icloud drive on my mac, and then disabled it, it moved all of my desktop files and documents to an archive. This happened multiple times. Now, I am no longer using this feature and I want to merge my 3 icloud archives (some of them partial or incomplete archives), into one archive, copying all files and duplicates into the same directories. However, I want to preserve my newest files and don't want to accidentally copy an old file over a more recently edited file of the same name. Furthermore, I don't want to accidentally copy a corrupt or "partially downloaded" file/folder over an intact file/folder of the same name. Essentially, how do I merge all of these folders, files, and subfolders into an orderly directory tree while preserving the integrity of the most up to date files and not accidentally copying over them? I would also like to preserve the file and folder structure so they all merge into one cohesive directory tree.

[image: My duplicate icloud archives expanded tree]
[image: My duplicate icloud archive directorys]

I did a little bit of research and it seems that rsync might be the tool to use, however, it also seems very complicated as well as very "Permanent". I don't want to use rSync unless I actually know what I am doing. After reading a bit more about rsync, I have gotten this far and think that a formula like this might do the trick:

```
rsync -ruvp --progress -topc -I --size-only -v -v ~/myicloudarchive2/* ~/myicloudarchive1
```

where my icloud archive directorys are located at `~/iCloud Drive (Archive) - 2` , `~/iCloud Drive (Archive) - 1` . and `~/iCloud Drive (Archive)`

Following this syntax, my "actual" command would look something like this:

Atomicamps-iMac:~ atomicamp$ `rsync -ruvp --progress -topc -I --size-only -v -v  /Users/atomicamp/iCloud\ Drive\ \(Archive\)\ -\ 2 /Users/atomicamp/iCloud\ Drive\ \(Archive\)\ -\ 1`

Can anyone either confirm, modify, or adjust the above syntax in order to help me achieve the results that I am looking for? Furthermore, can you also recommend any other ways to achieve this? Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Can anyone help me on this one? Anyone familiar with rsync and file merging? Please?

Comment: Can someone please answer this? Please?